# Tring to git pull with error :fatal: protocol error: bad pack header

Tags: git, github

**Help me pls. I am run this in terminal**
`git 
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 1301, done.
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.remote: Compressing objects:  16% (108/673)
remote: Compressing objectorting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: warning: packfile ./objects/pack/pack-e32996faab6453fb93de74bdf35f1585aa97f877.pack cannot be accessed
remote: error: unable to open object pack directory: ./objects/pack: Too many open files
remote: warning: packfile ./objects/pack/pack-e32996faab6453fb93de74bdf35f1585aa97f877.pack cannot be accessed
remote: fatal: failed to read object 9ddcb1eb21b57617c837f22e2335a9c1e98881c7: Too many open files
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header`

**Help me, I don't understand this problem.**
**Thank you.**

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this should be a comment, but I have not enough reputation to comment. So here we go.

Have you tried to  `git --bare fsck-objects --full` on your remote repository?

Besides that, might be a memory issue so try

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.SizeLimit "100m" 
git config --global pack.threads "1"
```